# How to make my navigation bar menu button work?

Tags: html, css

i dont know why my button dont show the menu when clicked ;
  i try almost everything i know, but i  cant define my problem.
  i use the "checkbox" trick to show the hamburger button when the site go under 500 px to show a resposive menu but i dont know w

i searched on google and youtube mìbut nothing i can help me put

```
HTML

<header>
<ul>
        <!-- ho aggiunto checkbox,toggle(bottone menu, id carrellore(carrello che compare con la mediaquery -->
        <input type="checkbox" id="toggle"/>
        <p id="carrellore"><a href="cart.jsp"><img src="./images/carrello.png"></a></p>
        <label for="toggle">&#9776;</label>
        <!-- ho aggiunto checkbox,toggle(bottone menu, id carrellore(carrello che compare con la mediaquery -->
        <li><a href="index.jsp">HOME</a><li>
        <li><a href="#catalogo">CATALOGO</a><li>
        <% if ((session.getAttribute("login_result")!=null) && ((Boolean)(session.getAttribute("login_result")))) {%>
        <li><a href="profile.jsp">PROFILO</a><li>
        <%} else { %>
        <a href="login.jsp">LOGIN</a><li>
        <%} %>
        <li id="carrello"><a href="cart.jsp"><img src="./images/carrello.png"></a></li>
        </ul>
    <div id="spazio">Spazio libero<br><br></div>
</header>



CSS

header ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #000000;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
header li {
    float: left;
}
header li a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px 15px;
    font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

header li a:hover {
    background-color: #0080ff;
}

label {
    margin: 0 40px 0 0;
    font-size: 30px;
    line-height: 70px;
    display: none;
    width: 14px;
    float: center;
    color: #ffffff;
}

#toggle {
    display:none;

}


#carrello {
    float: right;
}

#carrello img {
    height: 18px;
    width: auto;
    object-fit: contain;
}

#carrellore {
float:right;
display:none;

}

#carrellore img {
    height: 30px;
    width: auto;
    object-fit: contain;
}

#spazio {
    margin-top: 25px;
    visibility: hidden;
}

#logo {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
}
/* mediaquery per rendere il sito responsive */

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    #spazio {
    margin-top: 50px;
    visibility: hidden;
}



#carrellore {
       display: block;
        cursor: pointer;

}


    label {
        display: block;
        cursor: pointer;
        float: center;
}



  header li {
        background-color: #000000;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        width: 100%;
        display: none;

    }
   header li a {
        background-color: #000000;
        display: block;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #EAEAEB;
        margin: 0;


    }



    #toggle:checked + header li a {
        display:block ;
    }   

       “I’m setting up a new server, and want to support UTF-8 fully in my web application. Where do I need to set the encoding/charsets?”
}
```

the button dont trigger at all but the checkbox check

Comment: To start with your HTML is invalid - Only `li` can be children of a `ul`.

Comment: Also `#toggle:checked + header li a ` this does not reflect your HTML structure.

Comment: if i put they  outside they dont work

Comment: Then you need to re-think your methodology

Comment: i dont know how to do

Answer (score 0):

Try this code..

**HTML**

```
<header>
    <ul>
        <input type="checkbox" id="toggle"/>
        <p id="carrellore"><a href="cart.jsp"><img src="./images/carrello.png"></a></p>
        <label for="toggle">&#9776;</label>
        <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="index.jsp">HOME</a><li>
        <li><a href="#catalogo">CATALOGO</a><li>
        <% if ((session.getAttribute("login_result")!=null) && ((Boolean)(session.getAttribute("login_result")))) {%>
        <li><a href="profile.jsp">PROFILO</a><li>
        <%} else { %>
        <a href="login.jsp">LOGIN</a><li>
        <%} %>
        <li id="carrello"><a href="cart.jsp"><img src="./images/carrello.png"></a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="spazio">Spazio libero<br><br></div>
    </header>

**CSS**
header ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #000000;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
header li {
    float: left;
}
header li a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px 15px;
    font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}
header li a:hover {
    background-color: #0080ff;
}
label {
    margin: 0 40px 0 0;
    font-size: 30px;
    line-height: 70px;
    display: none;
    width: 14px;
    float: center;
    color: #ffffff;
}
#toggle {
    display:none;
}
#carrello {
    float: right;
}
#carrello img {
    height: 18px;
    width: auto;
    object-fit: contain;
}
#carrellore {
    float:right;
    display:none;
}
#carrellore img {
    height: 30px;
    width: auto;
    object-fit: contain;
}
header {
    padding-top: 66px;
}
body {
    margin: 0px;
}

#logo {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
}
/* mediaquery per rendere il sito responsive */

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    #spazio {
        margin-top: 50px;
        visibility: hidden;
    }
    #carrellore {
        display: block;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    label {
        display: block;
        cursor: pointer;
        float: center;
    }
    header ul.menu {
         display: none;
    }
    header li {
        background-color: #000000;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        width: 100%;
    }
    header li a {
        background-color: #000000;
        display: block;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #EAEAEB;
        margin: 0;
    }
    #toggle:checked + header li a {
        display:block ;
    }
}
```

**JQUERY**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('body').on('click','label',function() {
        $('.menu').slideToggle();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: this work in part, dont show the menu when in the homepage